# Minium - Element is not attached to the page document

Tags: javascript, selenium

I found a strange behaviour at Minim Developer; when i run the following code in the console:

```
$(".form-group").has($(".control-label").withText("Description"))
    .find(".cke_wysiwyg_frame").frames().find(".cke_editable").fill("Minium Test")
```

Minium is able to fill the field "Description"

But when I try to run the same code at the Step Definition, I have the following error:

> org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped
>   org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element
>   reference: element is not attached to the page document   (Session
>   info: chrome=68.0.3440.84)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498
>   (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds For
>   documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html Build
>   info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time:
>   '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z' System info: host: '47ZZQC2', ip:
>   '169.254.70.131', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_172' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Capabilities
>   {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false,
>   applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false,
>   browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.40.565498
>   (ea082db3280dd6..., userDataDir: C:\Users\~1.SIL\AppDat...},
>   cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts:
>   true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true,
>   locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false,
>   nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy:
>   normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false,
>   setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version:
>   68.0.3440.84, webStorageEnabled: true} Session ID: 103c08b587995e088faa269fbb46a4fd
>   (/minium/cucumber/internal/dsl.js#88(eval)#1)   at
>   modules/forms.js:136   at modules/forms.js:175   at
>   modules/forms.js:204   at steps/General/steps.js:95
>       at ?.

When I fill the fields: `features/Directory/Groups/groups.feature:48`

Any ideias to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems an issue related to the use of [interaction listener](https://minium.vilt.io/docs/learn/advanced-concepts/#interaction-listeners).

Are you adding any interaction listener to the browser configuration at world.js like this?

```
browser.configure()
    .defaultTimeout(5, timeUnits.SECONDS)
    .defaultInterval(500, timeUnits.MILLISECONDS)
    .interactionListeners()
      .add(minium.interactionListeners.onStaleElementReference().thenRetry())
      .add(...)
      ...
    .done();
```

If so, please move all the interaction Listeners to the [Base Expression](https://minium.vilt.io/docs/learn/advanced-concepts/#base-expressions). For exmple:

```
base = $(":root")
      .unless($(".modal").withCss("display", "block")).add(".modal-body")
      .with(minium.interactionListeners.onStaleElementReference().thenRetry())
      .with(...)
      ...
```

And run your code **without** the base expression, to avoid the call of interaction listener.